# Is SWT Link supported in Tabris?

Tags: android, ios7, tabris

I want to create hyperlink using Tabris UI framework. I tried with following code but sucsess. It works on browser (RAP). Android and iOS don't show anything.

```
Link link = new Link( parent, SWT.BORDER );
    String message = "Click on this hyperlink text <a href=\"http://www.eclipse.com/\">Eclipse</a>";
    link.setText( message );
    link.addSelectionListener( new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            System.out.println( "You have selected: " + e.text );
            getUI().getPageOperator().openPage( TestPage.class.getName() );
        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, link is not implemented right now.